# First instance does not match using find() method

Tags: java, regex

I am searching for the substrings with a number between forward slashes (eg. /n/) but the find() method always pass the first occurrence of the regex. 
Why? Is there something wrong with my regex?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\/)(\\d+)(\\/)"); 
Matcher m = p.matcher("A/8/E/5/F/6/G/7/H");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Comment: Are `m` and `m1` the same object?

Comment: oh yes, i'd messed up with editing my code

Comment: what do you mean by `always pass the first occurrence of the regex`?

Comment: I'm getting the response `/8/,
/5/,
/6/,
/7/`

Comment: I initially named it with m1 and edited it to m just to clean the code. Error still exists

Comment: You're grouping the regex, first `find()` should give you all matching groups (if any).

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the number to be printed use `m.group(2)`.

```
System.out.println(m.group(2));
```

Another solution is to use [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\/)(\\d+)(?=\\/)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("A/8/E/5/F/6/G/7/H");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this, as you need only the `number` between those `slashes`.

```
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

**group(0)** - gives the whole match `(/n/)`

**group(1)** - gives you the first slash `(/)`

**group(2)** - gives you the number `(n)`

**group(3)** - gives you the second slash `(/)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean to use m, your groups are '/', '8' and '/'. Try '\/(\d+)\/' for matching just '8'

Answer (score 0):

You must use `group(i)` to extract the i-th thing in brackets (excluding non-capturing groups).

`group(0)` or `group()` is the whole pattern.

So, for your example, you need `group(2)`.

Also note your code won't work on `8/5/4/3` since `8` can't match because it doesn't have a `/` before it, `4` can't match because `5` used the `/` in between and `3` can't match because it doesn't have a `/` after it. You need to include check for start of string (`^`) for `8` and end of string (`$`) for `3` and use look-ahead `(?=...)` for `4`.

I also used a non-capturing group `(?:...)`, so you can use `group(1)` instead of `group(2)` (this is the only difference `(?:...)` makes).

Also, you don't need to escape `/`.

Final code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:^|/)(\\d+)(?=/|$)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("8/5/4/3");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

[Regular expression reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

[Test](https://ideone.com/13rUGJ).